# Install JDK 9 on debian 10

Tags: linux, debian, jdk

For specific reasons I need to install JDK 9 on my Debian 10. But it seems like mission impossible. Can anyone share a tutorial ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 9 is out of support and has been deprecated, but you probably knew that already.

You can download the JDK from Oracle Java Archive:

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase9-archive-downloads.html

I'd recommend that you pick the `.tar.gz` packaged version, i.e. `jdk-9.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`.

Create a directory `/usr/local/java64` on your system. Extract that package to that directory:

```
mkdir /usr/local/java64
cd /usr/local/java64
tar xvf ~dakado/jdk-9.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz   #or wherever you placed the downloaded file
```

Then create a small script a few environment settings:

```
vi /usr/local/bin/this_software_needs_obsolete_java_9
```

Make the contents of the script as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java64/jdk-9.0.4
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
if [ "$1" != "" ]
then
    exec "$@"
fi
```

Make the script executable:

```
chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/this_software_needs_obsolete_java_9
```

Now, if you need to run some software `program_name` that requires Java 9, you'll be able to run it by prefixing its start-up command with this script:

```
this_software_needs_obsolete_java_9 program_name [parameters...]
```

If you need to use JDK 9's command line tools in a shell session, run this command first:

```
. /usr/local/bin/this_software_needs_obsolete_java_9
```

(The dot at the beginning is important: it makes the script run in your current shell so that shell's environment settings will get changed, instead of in a child shell that will die at the end of script along with the settings it made.)

This way, the obsolete JDK 9 is only used when explicitly required. Trying to set it as the system's default Java version is probably a bad idea.